# Comparison "as.. as.." word order

Tags: word-order, comparison

I've noticed that in comparison structure `as.. as..`, in my textbook, after the first `as` goes an adverb to compare and only after it goes additional information, like:

> You don't know **as much about cars as** I do.

So the question is, would this be correct:

> You don't know about cars **as much as** I do.

Comment: The "optional" adverbial element ***about cars*** can go *before, within*, or *after* the construction ***as much as X***, so there's also the third sequence ***You don't know as much as I do about cars*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers thanks a lot! Can you please submit it as an answer so I could close the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Correct:**

> You don't know as much about cars as I do.
>
> You don't know as much as I do about cars.

I would consider the other sentence (below) to be incorrect. If I'm wrong and it's technically correct, it's definitely awkward and strikes me as something that a non-native English speaker might say:

**You don't know about cars as much as I do.**

Instead, you could probably say:

> You don't know about cars like I do.